# Cannot enter text in an element inside an iframe using Cypress

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress

I have been going through cypress example recipes [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/blogs__iframes)  and implemented them too but I have not been able to enter text inside an element present in an iframe.
Here's a snapshot of the DOM:

[image: DOM snapshot]

The 'p' tag is where I need to type in text.

Here's my Cypress script to perform this action:

```
cy.get('div#risq-pros iframe').then($iframe => {
    const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body');
    cy.wrap($body).find('p').should('exist').type("some sample comment");
});
```

This is what I keep getting:

[image]

Eventually, it does not enter text.

Here is the error message:
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: p, but never found it. Queried from element: body.cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr

I am not sure where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently some known limitations using Cypress with iframes. 
Here are some links to some resources that might be useful for the issues you're experiencing.

Targeting elements within iframes (workaround):
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136

Article that expands on the above workaround:
https://medium.com/bratislava-angular/testing-an-app-inside-an-iframe-using-cypress-434a4d8b8bbe

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already gone through the above two links and I did try their examples but nothing worked for me.